# Find how does make call g++ when building

Tags: make, g++, cmake

I downloaded a program that in order to install it i have to execute the following commands:

```
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

The problem is that i am trying to customize the building flags without success. When doing a Make, i would like to be able to see exactly how make is calling g++, in order to check whether the flags and additional parameters are being used as expected.

Instead of this, i only see the typical:

```
[X%] Building CXX Object path/filename.cpp
```

Instead of this i would like to see exactly how g++ is being called.

Comment: If you changed the flags for cmake then you have to run `make clean` or delete build folder and start over

Comment: The answer appears to be in this [so] question: [Using Cmake with GNU Make: How can I see the exact commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670121/using-cmake-with-gnu-make-how-can-i-see-the-exact-commands)